# Strategies for Hosting 2 .NET Languages in Same Web App

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, hosting

I have 2 web sites (in Visual Studio - separate solutions) - one in VB.NET, one in C#.  Ideally, I'd like to make them both web application projects, compile each codebase into to a DLL, drop both DLLs in the bin and drop both sets of .aspx pages under web root folder.  So some aspx files would have Language="C#" and some Language="VB.NET", and in the bin you'd have /bin/MyVB6.dll, /bin/MyCSharp.dll.  The .aspx pages could be broken up into separate sub-directories.  Is this even possible? - Or would they need to be separate virtual directories/web apps in IIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why you can't do that (you can even have one assembly with the help of MSBUild and ILMerge). In a web application the language declaration does not matter and the classes are loaded from the pre-compiled dlls. In a web project each page is compiled at runtime in its own assembly. However you may need to [hack your Visual Studio's project files](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx) to build the source code in case of web application. To stay safe I suggest you [move your code to user controls in separate class library projects](http://aspalliance.com/335_sharing_a_user_control_across_web_applications).